# What are the dependecies I should add to use Oracel Object Store using java SDK

Tags: java, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, cloud-object-storage

Following is my build.gradle file with dependencies

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'com.oracle.oci.sdk:oci-java-sdk-bom:2.6.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.oracle.oci.sdk:oci-java-sdk-objectstorage'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

when I run the test cases I see following issue. What are the dependencies I am missing here

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.glassfish.jersey.spi.ComponentProvider not present
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:104)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:86)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:949)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType.getTypeArgument(GenericType.java:211)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType.<init>(GenericType.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientBootstrapBag$1.<init>(ClientBootstrapBag.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientBootstrapBag.getComponentProviders(ClientBootstrapBag.java:55)
```

Answer (score 1):

The class org.glassfish.jersey.spi.ComponentProvider  is found in jersey-server:

```
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-server', version: '2.26'
```

Comment: I found that version resolved transitively not havingnthe class. So, I forec teh version to implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.34' did the trick. Same dependency with version 2.33 didn't work. Thank you